# Facebook Mobile Browser and <hr> element

Tags: html, css, facebook, mobile, browser

i customizing css for facebook mobile browser. As css i have something like:

```
   body {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

    div#container > hr {        
        border-bottom: 8px dotted white;
        margin: 0px 16px 0px 16px;
    }
```

And as HTML something like:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
  Text 1
  <hr/>
  Text 2
</div>
</body>
```

Well, displaying it on facebook mobile browser i display *Text1* and *Text2* correctly but 

---

 element is ignored.
So i ask, as i can fix it? How i can display correcty 

---

 element in it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check that out [Why doesn’t my site display properly in the Facebook in-App Browser?](https://charlesr.co.uk/why-doesnt-my-site-display-properly-in-the-facebook-in-app-browser/)

you can also use `div` with `border-bottom` if the `<hr>` isn't working correctly.

Comment: Sincerly i don't want modify HTML becouse it work fine.  I have read article and much things i have fixed making a custom css and detecting user-agent for load it when site is displayed in facebook mobile browser. Now need only solve it.  PS: when i disable css, the <hr> element is displayed correctly as a line.

Comment: did you disable the whole css or just the css which is related to ``hr``?

Comment: No disable all css and i see hr as a line. But with property border is as if came ignored.